# Sums of nested radicals

Tags: analysis, continued-fractions, nested-radicals

Is there a known example of an infinite sum of finitely nested radicals that evaluates to a given value?

Or an infinite sum of convergents of an infinite continued fraction? The finitely nested radical bears the same relationship to the infinitely nested radical that the convergent bears to the infinite continued fraction, in case there is ambiguity.

If there is, is it possible that someone would kindly provide a reference?

Edit: With convergence to be assured, where necessary, by any suitable factor like factorials or powers etc., to diminish the convergents rapidly enough. . To rephrase the question, are there any examples of such sums involving nested radicals or convergents of continued fractions?

Comment: For an infinite series to converge, the terms have to converge to zero. That's not possible for the convergents to a (regular) continued fraction.

Comment: Thank you, but that was implicit in the question, I apologize. What I meant was a series in which the convergents are suitably weighted to ensure convergence, for example by factors like exponentials, or the factorials, or anything else to ensure convergence.